# Access report now only showing some records

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an Access report which has always worked perfectly in the past.

It shows any cases that have a deadline approaching in the coming seven days.

As of today, however, it isn't showing all cases - only some.

For example, I have a case whose deadline is 24/11/2016 (today is 22/11/2016).  Previously, this would have shown up in the report.  It didn't.

I then created a dummy case with the same deadline of 24/11/2016 and ran the report again.  It showed up.

I changed the date in the deadline field of the previous record and it wasn't showing up in the report no matter what I tried (remember that the test one worked).

I am using the same form to work on both records and they are both stored in the same table.

In short: the report is only showing some of the case deadlines and not all, even though the deadline dates definitely meet the query criteria within the report.

What could be a possible reason for the sudden change in behaviour?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the query (in SQL view):

```
SELECT [CCG Complaints].[Ref no], [CCG Complaints].[DEADLINE (25 WD)], [CCG Complaints].FirstName, [CCG Complaints].LastName, [CCG Complaints].IO, [CCG Complaints].DateDraftReceived, [CCG Complaints].Status, [CCG Complaints].CCG
FROM [CCG Complaints]
WHERE ((([CCG Complaints].[DEADLINE (25 WD)]) Between Date() And Date()+7) 
  AND (([CCG Complaints].DateDraftReceived) Is Null) 
  AND (([CCG Complaints].Status)="Open"));
```

Comment: Please post the SQL for the report.

Comment: I have updated the question with the SQL code (from SQL view in query builder).

Comment: That will work if `[DEADLINE (25 WD)]` is a field of data type Date. So something else is going on.

Comment: You have 3 criteria - one of them must be violated by the record in question.

Comment: Just to confirm, 1[DEADLINE (25WD)]` is a field of `Data` type.  As mentioned, the report appears to not be working on some older/pre-existing records.

Comment: @Andre That's it!  The fields that weren't being picked up had a value in `Date Draft Received:`. I removed the value to test and sure enough it appeared. Thank you.